# How to develop a Ruby GEM without having to install it first?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm developing a GEM that I've forked and I'm trying to modify it slightly for my app.

I'm finding it difficult and time consuming because for every change I make I have to

1. uninstall
2. build
3. re-install
4. run the app

Is there an easier way of which doesn't require repeating all steps above?

Comment: You mean to run an app with your gem version?

Comment: I mean how can my app run and use the GEM that I just updated without needing to first install that gem. Can I update the app GEM file to use that gem straight from a directory which I can specify instead of the default GEMs directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### To use it in some app using bundler

If what you mean is for using it in a app to test it / use it, you can just specify a path for your gem or even point to a git repo in the Gemfile http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html

Like

```
gem "mygem", :path => "~/code/gems/mygem"
```

### To use it as a standalone gem. i.e: like rspec or rake that can run outside of an app.

Just specify the path to your gem binary when running the gem command, like:

```
$ ~/path_to_my_gem/bin/mygem some args
```

If you can execute inside your gem directory (i.e: the command does not create files in the current directory, or needs any specific files from the current directory), just do this:

```
$ ./bin/mygem some args
```

Note that this last one is just for future reference, I think it's not applicable in the OP context.

Comment: Does this work if the GEM contains executable scripts similar to how you could for instance just execute 'bundle install' in the terminal?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your last question. Maybe you should try it?

Comment: What I mean is for the test to work I should be able to go to my App directory and execute a script from the GEM in the terminal. It's similar to how you go to your app directory and in the terminal and type "bundle install". "Bundle Install" comes from the Bundler gem but it installs a scripts called "Bundle" which is accessible in the terminal. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. So the gem works alone or does it require to be in a Rails app or something?

Comment: if you can provide a link to the gem repo if it's public

Comment: Sorry not public, but I'm modifying Jekyll.  It has 'jekyll build' command which I need to be able to execute without needing to install the GEM while I'm editing it.

Comment: btw, really appreciate your help.

Comment: Ok, I think you can just execute it with `~/path_to_your_gem/bin/jekyll build`

Comment: Do I need to include your suggested line abobe in my GEM file too?

Comment: nop, That line is just to run the binary. You don't need to change anything.

Comment: No I meant the other suggested `gem "mygem", :path => "~/code/gems/mygem"
`

Comment: If you just want to run the binary I don't think you have to change any Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

use require_relative to include your files:

```
require_relative 'yourgem/yourclass'
```

This is the [documentation for the function](http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Kernel.html).